# A locally injection is an injection for the real line?

Tags: analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous mapping, if for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection.

If $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and for any $x\in (a,b)$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection.

If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and for any $x\in [a,b]$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection.

If $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$,$n \geq 2$, and for any $x\in (a,b)$, there exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, such that $f$ is an injection on $U$, then $f$ is an injection.

Are these all right?

Comment: The last one isn't.  Consider $f(x)=(\cos x, \sin x)$.

Comment: The first three are true because the order properties of the real line prevent a function from being able to loop back on itself. As Kyle Miller has demonstrated, the same is not true of $\Bbb R^n$ for $n > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a counterexample for the last statement. Here is a sketch of proof for the other ones:

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Assume by contradiction that $a \neq b$. Then, the interval $[a,b]$ is a compact set where $f$ attains a maximum ($M$) and a minimum ($m$) (Extreme Value Theorem). Either $M$ or $m$ is not equal to $f(a)$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $f(a)\neq M=f(x)$ for some $x$. What can you say about $x$?

Comment: Inyectivity is a property of a function, not a point. Consider the behavior of the function around x.